# mod-pbxproj, how to add custom framework to XCode Project file

Tags: python, ios, xcode

I want to add my own framework `Lib.framework` to xcode project using mod-pbxproj python script. When I use function:

```
project.add_file_if_doesnt_exist('/Path/To/My/Lib/Lib.framework', tree='<absolute>', weak=True)
```

this framework exists in libraries list in XCode editor, but headers search path is not updated, so other files cannot include headers from that framework.

How to properly add custom framework to xcode project using mod-pbxproj script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't read documentation enough carefully

```
project.add_framework_search_paths('/Path/To/My/Lib/', recursive=False)
```